# Nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-jdbc

> org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO CCBS2.CAM_POS_HEADER_INTERFACE (POS_REGISTRATION_NO,         RECORD_ORIGINAL,PROVIDER_CODE,TOTAL_INVOICE_AMOUNT,        INDIVIDUAL_CORPORATE,EQUIPMENT_INSTALLED_BY_CX,        EQUIPMENT_OWNED_BY_CX,SALE_TYPE,EXISTING_CX_PROFILE_NO,        EXISTING_BILLING_ADDRESS_ID,IDENTIFICATION_TYPE,        IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER,DOB_COMPANY_REGISTRATION_DATE,SEX,        NATIONALITY,TAX_POLICY,VAT_REGISTRATION_NO,TITLE,        OTHER_NAME,SURNAME,CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE1,CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE2,        CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_LINE3,CUSTOMER_POSTAL_CODE,CUSTOMER_CITY,        CUSTOMER_COUNTRY,EMAIL_ADDRESS,BRANCH_CODE,AGENT_CODE,        AGENT_LOCATION,CREATED_USER,UPDATED_USER,        UPDATED_DATE,TAX_EXCEMPTED,POS_SALES_ID,PRE_POST,        DEALER_MSISDN,REQUEST_CHANNEL,CX_ID_NUMBER,CX_ID_TYPE,SALE_EXTERNAL_PARTY,CPOS_INVOICE_NO,PROMOTER_ID)   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,    ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?)]; No more data to read from socket; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket

From time to time insert to table CAM_POS_HEADER_INTERFACE fails. Then entire application hangs. If the session is killed only the tables are getting released. This is happening only sometimes for the particular table only.

I'm using Java version 6, Spring version 4.0.6, ojdbc6. I went through the answers provided for the previous posts in the forum. But nothing helped to fix my issue.